# I am not able to pass the values from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to get the values from the edittext from one activity and trying to send that and receive that values in another activity. But I am unable to get the values. however I am not opening the receiving activity just after the values are entered . I am opening that activity after login. The code is as follows

MainActivity.java

```
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successful Registration", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login_Activity.class);


                    String name,mobile;
                    name = Username.getText().toString();
                    mobile = Usermob.getText().toString();


                    Bundle i2 = new Bundle();
                    i2.putString("uname", name);
                    i2.putString("unumber",mobile);
                    i.putExtras(i2);
                    startActivity(i);
                    /*Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "captcha not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
```

referralPage.java

```
                    package com.mws.tms_application;

                    import android.content.Intent;
                    import android.os.Bundle;
                    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
                    import android.widget.EditText;
                    import android.widget.TextView;

                    public class referralPage extends AppCompatActivity {


                        @Override
                        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                            setContentView(R.layout.activity_referral_page);




                           // MainActivity mn=new MainActivity();
                            TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.referralcode);
                            EditText ed1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_edtext);
                            EditText ed2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usermob_no_edtext);

                            Intent intent = getIntent();
                          /*  String name = intent.getExtras().getString("uname");
                            String mobile = intent.getExtras().getString("unumber");*/

                    /*
                            name=ed1.getText().toString();
                            name=name.substring(0,3);
                            number=ed2.getText().toString();
                            number=number.substring(7,9);*/
                           Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                            System.out.print("INtent called");
                            if (bundle != null) {
                                String name = bundle.getString("uname");
                                System.out.print("INtent runned");
                                tv.setText(name/*+bundle.getExtras().getString("unumber")*/);
                            }
                            else{
                                tv.setText("Your referral code");
                            }


                           // tv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(name).append(mobile).toString());
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: When you say you are not opening the receiver activity on entering, then where have you put this code in your MainActivity.

Comment: The Bundle you sent to the LoginActivity is not available for referralPage Activity only because it is being opened from there. And yes, add the code for opening referralPage Activity.

Answer (score 0):

**try this send data like this**

```
String name,mobile;
name = Username.getText().toString();
mobile = Usermob.getText().toString();

Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login_Activity.class); 
i.putExtra("name", name);
i.putExtra("mobile", mobile);
startActivity(i);
```

**now receive data in another activity like this**

```
String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
String mobile = getIntent().getExtras().getString("mobile");
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity name is specified in your code is not correct. You must specify the name of the activity in which you want to pass data. Here, you have created Intent for starting "Login_Activity.java" while data handling code is written in "referralPage.java".

Replace

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login_Activity.class);
```

with

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, referralPage.class);
```